# How can I root LG Optimus Net (LG P690)?

Tags: rooting, lg

I recently bought a new phone and decided to play with my old LG P690 with Gingerbread 2.3.4.

I want to root it using a Linux PC. 
I tried to exploit it using `psneuter` and `zergRush`.
I pushed them into the phone and gave it executable permissions. 
Both tools are failed to obtain root access.

Rebooting into recovery mode just factory resets the phone without asking a thing.

Are there any other options left to root the phone?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I've had multiple devices rooted with [KingoRoot](https://www.kingoapp.com/) 
It's pretty easy as it requires only a few clicks. You can see that in the Devices that your model is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I was too hasty in saying psneuter and zergRush didn't work. Despite the fact the exploits indicated failure. Upon next reboot when I attempted to try something I got a root shell in the adb shell. So they indeed worked.

Lesson learned: even if the exploits indicate failure try rebooting they might have actually worked.